# Night Owl DVR-HDA10PB-162_RS admin password reset

Tags: passwords

we had Night OWl DVR-HDA10PB-162_RS 16 Channel H.264 DVR W/2TB HDD, but we forgot the admin's password. 
We googled website, we did not find out any workaround.
Some of guys suggest to open the box and remove the battery, but the solution does not figure out our Model. 
We called the support center, they told us to send solution by email, but we do not get any more now...

Answer (score 2):

At last we figured out the issue by register NightOwl on http://nightowlsp.com/, and created a ticket to describe what we wanted. They send back an email to give us temporary password for admin.
We login into our night owl by the temporary password. Great!
The NightOwl online support is perfect!

Comment: This is True. Really thanks for the idea. I post a request and after an hour it was answered with a temporary password. I gave them the model and the serial number to make the process faster. A really good experience. Recommended!

Answer (score 1):

Night owl has an amazing customer service.They are very responsive and attentive.Couldnt ask for a better customer support nor a better survallence system.If you call and can confirm a couple of questions that the system owner should know then theyll have you up and going in less than 5